# Comments in FlashBuilder (aka Flex) mm.cfg file?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flash-builder

FlashBuilder's undocumented `mm.cfg` file has a lot of cool options as shown [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html) and [elsewhere](http://jpauclair.net/mm-cfg-secrets/).  But what about comments?

Can anyone out there verify if comments are supported in FlashBuilder's `mm.cfg` file?

If so what are the rules?  For example:

```
REM  .bat style comment
;    .ini style comment
#    shell style comment
/*   C Style comment          */
//   C++ style comment
--   SQL style comment
<!-- XML style comment        -->
```

Are multi-line comments allowed?  Must comments be on separate lines?

Comment: mm.cfg file used for trace output. it will activate only when using flash debugger player to execute application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'rem' seems to work as expected in mm.cfg

'rem' lines are silently ignored without errors. tested with google chrome (13.0.782.220 m windows) and debug flash player (10,2,159,1 installed)

```
TraceOutputBuffered=0
ErrorReportingEnable = 0
MaxWarnings=1000000
TraceOutputFileEnable = 1
rem PreloadSwf = D:\Dev\PBLabsProfiler\dist\Agent.swf
```

'rem' is a single line comment. multi-line comments not allowed.

be sure to restart your browser to have mm.cfg changes take effect